# Save and Verify the Card, Charge Later - Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm setting up my first Shopify store and would like to offer a free trial of a product.  The basic idea is the customer is shipped the product at no charge and has so many days to try out and return the product.  If the product is not returned within the time period they are charged the amount agreed upon up front.

Within Shopify there is only the option to capture payment immediately or to authorize and then manually capture payment later (7 day auth limitation).

What I would like to do is validate the credit card, but not pre-auth, then the ship the product to the customer for try out.  If they decide to keep the product then I charge them 30 days later as agreed by the customer.

The method I want to use with Shopify is the same as detailed by Braintree here

https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1080637-collect-payment-at-a-later-date-aka-extend-authorization-

in the section "Save and Verify the Card, Charge Later".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option as you see it: *authorize and then manually capture payment later*

As an alternative, you could always capture the money, and if they actually do return it, refund them the money. That is how all TV sales work and they make bazillions doing that, so why not follow their lead?

Comment: With Shopify's "authorize and then manually capture payment later" the authorization happens the minute the user checks out and you only have 7 days to capture payment or it will not be honored.  This does not help.  Also, capturing payment and then refunding is not ideal for many reasons.  We expect a very high exchange turn over on product as this is merchandise that is worn and so fit/look once customer receives it is often not what they like so they send back in and get something different.  By doing charges and refunds constantly then we are incurring huge overheads in transaction fees.

Comment: Join the rest of the world losing money with refunds, shipping etc. You cannot use Shopify in any other ways. It's rigid sure, but so are most gateways. You have no choice. If you need a wider window than 3-7 days on transactions, Shopify won't work for you.

Comment: @bigtunacan If it helps, I think Shopify's transaction fees are reversed when you do a refund :) This is the case for Shopify Payments anyway - not sure about other gateways.